# How to force filename completion in shell buffers to use quotes instead of backslashes

Tags: shell-mode, quote

I have a directory with the file `a file name with spaces` and in Emacs I have a bash in a shell buffer. Rhen  I type

```
ls a<TAB>
```

and shell mode completes to

```
a\ file\ name\ with\ space
```

However I would like the completion to look like

```
'a file name with space'
```

How can I achieve this? What function do I have modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting question. It's not configurable at all, so I recommend looking at `pcomplete-insert-entry`. This is where the completed text is inserted, and it's what calls `comint-quote-filename`. Note that it handles some fun edge cases that you'll also have to handle. In particular, if there's already a backslash in the buffer then it handles the insertion a little differently so as to avoid ending up with an extra backslash. You'll want to add something similar for quote characters, I'm sure.

You'll also probably want to make sure that your changes don't break anything when pcomplete is used in other modes. It's mostly used by eshell, but in principle it can be used with anything that uses comint-mode.

Comment: AFAICT, it should be `pcomplete-quote-argument` which in my version of emacs is an obsolete alias to `comint-quite-filename`.

Comment: I recommend changing `pcomplete-insert-entry` instead, since it also needs to handle the edge cases. Have it call a new function `pcomplete-quote-filename-with-actual-quotes` instead of `comint-quote-filename`; that's less likely to break anything.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thanks. Detail question: When I look at `pcomplete.el` I can see that `pcomplete-insert-entry` calls `comint-quote-filename` not `pcomplete-quote-filename`.

Comment: Oops, just a typo.